# SQL- BCP Export ORDER BY with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, csv, bcp

I am trying to do a bcp data export to a CSV file. But I found that the data in my CSV is out of order. So I am trying to add ORDER BY to properly sort in the correct order. I am using UNION ALL to bring in the column headers, however that appears to create issues when trying to use ORDER BY.

```
bcp "select CHAR(34)+""SampleNo""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Location Code""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Location Description""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Collection Date""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Submit Date""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""File Name""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Analysis Code""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Analyte Name""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Result""+CHAR(34)+CHAR(44) union all select CHAR(34)+SAMPNO+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+LOCCODE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+LOCDESCR+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+COLDATE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+SUBDATE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+MYSAMPNO+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+ACODE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+ANALYTE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+RESULT+CHAR(34)+CHAR(44) FROM [TEST].dbo.DATA_EXPORT ORDER BY ""SAMPLE_NO"" " QUERYOUT '+ @file + ' -S SERV2012R2 -U sa -P password -c -t","
```

I get the following errors:

```
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 408
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]A constant 
expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.
```

And...

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column 
level collations
BCP copy out failed
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that the CSV data follows the same ordering as the database table.

Comment: Please format your code a bit better - that's unreadable, also can you be clearer about what the problem is?

Comment: @MarkTaylor Thanks for the feedback Mark. Made some edits and clarified what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, instead of using the column name I just needed to use the field position. So in this case it was position 1, "ORDER BY 1".

```
bcp "select CHAR(34)+""SampleNo""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Location Code""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Location Description""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Collection Date""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Submit Date""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""File Name""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Analysis Code""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Analyte Name""+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+""Result""+CHAR(34)+CHAR(44) union all select CHAR(34)+SAMPNO+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+LOCCODE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+LOCDESCR+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+COLDATE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+SUBDATE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+MYSAMPNO+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+ACODE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+ANALYTE+CHAR(34),CHAR(34)+RESULT+CHAR(34)+CHAR(44) FROM [TEST].dbo.DATA_EXPORT ORDER BY 1 " QUERYOUT '+ @file + ' -S SERV2012R2 -U sa -P password -c -t","
```

Now this has created another problem. Since I am using UNION ALL to generate the header in the file, after apply the ORDER BY 1 clause, the headers are now at the bottom of the file. Wonk wonk wonk...